# vb.net mysql query running in single click

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, mysql-connector

I need to get mysql login data from a notepad file saved in the computer, connect with the server & run a query, all in a one single click.

1. i have this code, but the problem is there is a "public Sub Savenames(ByRef sqlstatement As String)" section & i do not know how to include it into the button click event.

   ```
       Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
       Public Class Admission
       Private Sub MetroButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles admission_btn_save.Click
        If System.IO.File.Exists("D:\DBSystem\Connection\connconfig.dbs") = True Then

       Dim strFile As String = "D:\DBSystem\Connection\connconfig.dbs"
       Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
       Dim ip As String
       Dim port As String
       Dim userid As String
       Dim password As String
       Dim database As String

       'reading
       ip = sr.ReadLine()
       port = sr.ReadLine()
       userid = sr.ReadLine()
       password = sr.ReadLine()
       database = sr.ReadLine()
       sr.Close()


       'default connection code
       Dim serverstring As String = "server=" & ip & ";port=" & port & ";database=" & database & ";user ID=" & userid & ";password=" & password & ";OldGuids=true"
       Dim sqlconnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
       sqlconnection.ConnectionString = serverstring

       Try
           If sqlconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
               sqlconnection.Open()
               MsgBox("Successfully connected to database!")
           Else
               sqlconnection.Close()
               MsgBox("connection closed!")

           End If

       Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.ToString)
       End Try

       'reading from notepad config file




   Else
       MessageBox.Show("Do not have any previous configurations!", "Error",
          MessageBoxButtons.OK)
   End If
   End Sub

      'i need to eliminate this sub and add it into the button click event
      Public Sub Savenames(ByRef sqlstatement As String)
   Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

   With cmd
       .CommandText = sqlstatement
       .CommandType = CommandType.Text
       .Connection = sqlconnection
       .ExecuteNonQuery()

   End With
   sqlconnection.Close()
   MsgBox("Successfully recorded!")
   sqlconnection.Dispose()

   End Sub

    End Class
   ```

i need to eliminate that "Public Sub Savenames(ByRef sqlstatement As String)" section & add it into the button click event. i do not have that much of a programming knowledge since i'm self learning. any idea how to do this? (please show me the modified code)

Comment: You could just call the procedure inside `MetroButton1_Click` event of the button: `Dim name As String = Savenames("somestringvalue")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add the task of that sub to the Part where you are checking the Connection.Since connection is already open no need of opening it again..Also don't forget to give the Query statement..(I guess insert )

```
 Private Sub MetroButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles admission_btn_save.Click
            If System.IO.File.Exists("D:\DBSystem\Connection\connconfig.dbs") = True Then

                Dim strFile As String = "D:\DBSystem\Connection\connconfig.dbs"
                Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
                Dim ip As String
                Dim port As String
                Dim userid As String
                Dim password As String
                Dim database As String

                'reading
                ip = sr.ReadLine()
                port = sr.ReadLine()
                userid = sr.ReadLine()
                password = sr.ReadLine()
                database = sr.ReadLine()
                sr.Close()


                'default connection code
                Dim serverstring As String = "server=" & ip & ";port=" & port & ";database=" & database & ";user ID=" & userid & ";password=" & password & ";OldGuids=true"
                Dim sqlconnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
                sqlconnection.ConnectionString = serverstring

                Try
                    If sqlconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                        sqlconnection.Open()
                        MsgBox("Successfully connected to database!")
                        Dim sqlstatement As String = "Insert int >>>Your Query"
                        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

                        With cmd
                            .CommandText = sqlstatement
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            .Connection = sqlconnection
                            .ExecuteNonQuery()

                        End With
                        sqlconnection.Close()
                        MsgBox("Successfully recorded!")
                    Else
                        sqlconnection.Close()
                        MsgBox("connection closed!")

                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try

                'reading from notepad config file




            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Do not have any previous configurations!", "Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            End If
        End Sub
```